# how to find out if a number is sum of a number and its polindrom in a short time

Tags: c, primes

I want to write a program to find all numbers less than an specific number that are equal to sum of a number and its polindrome.and this is my code, and it works correctly,but take too long time.what should I do to reduce it's time?

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long int isprime(long long int b)
{
    long long int i,m;
    for(i=2;i*i<=b;i++)
    {
        if(b%i==0)
        {
            return 0;

        }
    }
        return 1;
}

long long int m(long long int a){
    long long int l=0;
        while (a>0){
        l=l*10+(a%10);
        a/=10;
    }
    return l;
}

int main(){
    long long int i = 0,cnt = 0,a= 0,num;
    scanf("%lld",&a);
    for (i=2;i<=a; i++){
        if (isprime(i) == 1){
            for (num=1;num<i; num++){
            if (num == m(i-num)){
                cnt ++;
                break;
                //printf("%d\n",i);

            }
        }
        }
    }
    printf("%lld", cnt);
}
```

Comment: I did not understand the problem. As much as I know, a number has no palindrome. 'palindrome' is a number that its reverse is equal to the number itself.  
Also, how the primes are connected?

Comment: Question is better suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: 1)Prepare a prime number in advance.

Comment: Checking every even number for being a prime number is inefficient. As you are interested in only prime numbers you might want to take a look at the sieve of Eratosthenes (of course not if you really want to check long long int numbers).

Comment: There are several ways to enhance your prime-checking code. 1) Check if b%2, and later only check if b%i for *even* numbers i, *or*, if you want to really dive into this, use Erathostenes' sieve. 2) Don't check up to b-1. You only need to check up to the square root of b.

Comment: 3) If you're ok with abstract math, checck the deterministic variant of Miller-Rabin -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants or the Elliptic curve method -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality . But it's not yet clear what your question is, so please clarify it a bit more.